# Handling variations between difference in time output R

Tags: r, time, format

I have a df where I am subtracting the differences of times of two dates using a unique ID to do so. I do get the correct output however, I have an issue with consistency in the output of the time difference. For example on row 2 a difference of 1.500 is calculated which is 90 minutes or 1 Hr and 30 minutes. On row 8 there is a difference of 20.00 calculated which is 20 minutes.

I have tried to convert this column to a standard time format but I am not successful. If I try to covert the column to minutes, times that are already in minutes are artificially higher while those in hours are correct. Any feedback anyone can provide to allow me to have a way to convert this column to a consistent format preferably minutes will be extremely helpful.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(anytime)

df = vroom::vroom(file = "datasample.csv")

df$Time=anytime(df$Time)

df=df %>% 
  group_by(x4) %>%
  mutate(difference = ifelse(Time == max(Time), max(Time) - min(Time), NA))


##Attempting to convert column to standard format
# diffs.hours <- floor(as.numeric(df$difference))
# diffs.minutes <- (as.numeric(df$difference)%%1 * 60)
 

#60  * as.numeric(times(df$difference))
```

[image: Displaying Sample DF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difftime` to subtract time using which you can control the units.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
        group_by(x4) %>%
        mutate(difference = ifelse(Time == max(Time), 
                             difftime(max(Time), min(Time), units = 'mins'), NA))
```